# Trying to setup a custom authentication in Laravel

Tags: laravel

So I have no experience in Laraval and have been trying to make a Auth that doesn't use the default table Users.
I followed some tutorials and ended up with a custom Auth that, atleast, doesn't give an error of incorrect database database or someting like this, but when trying to LogIn keeps giving the error of wrong password or username.

The table that im trying to use is called **usuaris** and the columns to use for the login are **nomUsuari** and **contrasenya**.

This is my custom authentication file:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class customAuth extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'usuaris';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nomUsuari','contrasenya'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'contrasenya',
    ];


    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
      return $this->contrasenya;
    }
}
```

The Auth.php conf:

```
 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'usuaris',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'usuaris',
        ],

    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'usuaris' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\customAuth::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],


    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'usuaris' => [
            'provider' => 'usuaris',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

    ],
```

And the function to validate:

```
function checklogin(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nomUsuari' => 'required',
            'contrasenya' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user_data = array(
            'nomUsuari' => $request->get('nomUsuari'),
            'password' => $request->get('contrasenya')
        );

        //print_r($user_data);

        if(Auth::attempt($user_data)){
            return redirect('successlogin');
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', 'Datos incorrectos');
        }
    }
```

[Image of the table ususaris and user im trying to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwryK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$user_data = array(
            'nomUsuari' => $request->get('nomUsuari'),
            'password' => $request->get('contrasenya')
        );
```

to

```
$user_data = array(
            'nomUsuari' => $request->get('nomUsuari'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->get('contrasenya'))
        );
```

And remove

```
public function getAuthPassword()
    {
      return $this->contrasenya;
    }
```